# Composer install Symfony 3.4 - bootstrap.php.cache

Tags: php, symfony, nginx, doctrine

During the installation of my project, I had to install and update my composer. However I can't do it beacause composer tells me this :

```
> Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap
> Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache

Warning: require_once(C:\Projects\private\p1\../app/bootstrap.php.cache): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Projects\private\p1\bin\console on line 11

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'C:\Projects\private\p1\bin/../app/bootstrap.php.cache' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\Projects\private\p1\bin\console on line 11
Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache handling the post-install-cmd event terminated with an exception


  [RuntimeException]
  An error occurred when executing the ""cache:clear --no-warmup"" command:


  Warning: require_once(C:\Projects\private\p1\bin/../app/bootstrap.php.cache): failed to open stream
  : No such file or directory in C:\Projects\private\p1\bin\console on line 11

  Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'C:\Projects\private\p1\bin/../app/bootstrap.php.cache' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\Projects\private\p1\bin\console on line 11
```

I've been searching an answer for 2 days and I've tried everything I coulded see on the internet...

I don't know if you need something else but please help me

Comment: Can you update your question with the contents of your `composer.json` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the  bootstrap.php.cache file was not created for different reasons. Normally it should be generated after running `composer install` in your project directory.

If you need to generate it manually, just run the following command in your Symfony project folder:

```
php vendor/sensio/distribution-bundle/Sensio/Bundle/DistributionBundle/Resources/bin/build_bootstrap.php
```

If you have the new Symfony 3 folder structure you need to add three arguments:

```
php vendor/sensio/distribution-bundle/Sensio/Bundle/DistributionBundle/Resources/bin/build_bootstrap.php var app new
```

The file will then be generate in var/bootstrap.php.cache instead of app/bootstrap.php.cache.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and explanations, it worked ! See you :)

Comment: It was the least I could do.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to solve your problem :

1. run this command  :  `bin/console cache:clear --env=prod`
2. run this `chown www-data:www-data projectDirectory`
3. run this command `SYMFONY_ENV=prod composer install --no-dev -o --prefer-dist`
4. run this command `chown www-data:www-data projectDirectory`

Comment: Could you check if you have the file or not? It is suppoosed to be generated by post install commands by composer. So either that fails, or your webserver does not have access to read anything in that folder.

Comment: I do not have it but I've seen that it was in my gitignore file, I don't know if this change something

Comment: try with my next response